# Though I have Java enabled in the server, I'm facing java path issue

Tags: java, gradle, bamboo

**I'm generating war file using Gradle using shell script but  I'm getting the below error.**

```
ls
cd ClaimCenter1003
javac -version
chmod 777 gwb.sh
./gwb.sh warTomcatDbcp
```

```
05-Jun-2020 13:22:54    ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
05-Jun-2020 13:22:54     
05-Jun-2020 13:22:54    Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
05-Jun-2020 13:22:54    location of your Java installation.
```

**Java is set in all the bamboo servers though not working in many server through the console but when I triggered the build from command Line it is working fine.**

The build is working in some servers giving me the output as I needed:

```
javac 1.8.0_161
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:01    Downloading file:/opt/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/GUID-GCCA-VAR/ClaimCenter1003/gradle/wrapper/./gradle.zip
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:02    .................................................................................
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:04    
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:04    Welcome to Gradle 5.1.1!
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:04    
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:04    Here are the highlights of this release:
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:04     - Control which dependencies can be retrieved from which repositories
build   05-Jun-2020 13:18:04     - Production-ready configuration avoidance APIs
```

Build going through when did in CLI

[CLI BUILD IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHm4Y.png)

Please help me through this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Either JAVA_HOME or PATH is not set on the build agents which fail.

If i were in your situation, I'd primarily take steps to ensure those exist.

An easy way would be to "dockerize" your build by simply using docker, e.g.:
`` docker run openjdk:{JDK_VERSION} bash `./buildscript.sh` ``.

The other way is to ensure java is installed correctly on your build agent prior to starting the actual build steps. The problem will be that it appears your build agent instance is reused by other builds, so even if this works it may cause other errors downstream, hence I recommend virtualization your build via docker.

I'd check if both $JAVA and $JAVA_HOME are correctly set and if not, to either explicitly install java (see for example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/generic-linux-install.html to steps to install amazon coretto openjdk) or to set the environment variables manually if you're sure java exists on the target machine.

Comment: Alex thank you for the quick reply. JAVA_HOME and Path are set and I can able to build through CLI but the problem only occurs when I do it through Bamboo GUI.